# Query can not execute though HQL

Tags: java

I have a database. I connected to it from IDEA.

The project of the restaurant menu and in the description of the data fields in the Menu class I indicated a link or a link (@TABLE) to my table:

```
@Entity
 @Table(name="menu")
 public class Menu {
```

Here is my method with the query HQL:

```
private static void priceFromTo(){
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Input minimum price: ");
Double min = sc.nextDouble();
System.out.println("Input the maximum price: ");
Double max = sc.nextDouble();
System.out.println("We have these dishes with your price : ");
System.out.println();

Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT menu FROM Menu menu WHERE menu.price BETWEEN :min AND :max", Menu.class);
query.setParameter("max",max);
```

query.setParameter("min", min);
    List list = query.getResultList();

System.out.println("Size of list result = " + list.size());

It does not issue any errors, but it does not make changes in the database (it does not receive data from the database), I have already tried to delete something and output it to the console. Now checking whether it works or not using the size LIST, but it, you guessed it, LIST.size = 0, although there are enough suitable rows in the database.

Maybe It is not connect to the database, but even in the logs it refers to my database.

If necessary, I will share more code through GitHub, but I think that It is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried turning the log to verbose and seeing what the actual SQL output is?

See [here](https://thoughts-on-java.org/hibernate-logging-guide/)

The command will probably look something like

```
log4j.logger.org.hibernate=verbose
```